# What happens to flight operations if no ARFF vehicle is available at a CAT 3 airfield?

Tags: airport, firefighting

There is a domestic VFR airfield that has the DHC6 Twin Otter as its critical aircraft operating there, making the field an ICAO CAT 1B aerodrome. With regards to ARFF it is a CAT 3 aerodrome and requires 1 ARFF vehicle.

If that vehicle is not in service (broken or not operational), would that mean that the airfield is now CAT 0 for ARFF? Can that airfield remain open/operational if there are commercial flights being performed to and from it (VFR only)?